# What is the relationship between poisson, gamma, and exponential distribution?

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, gamma-distribution

I'm having a hard time understanding the intuitive relationship between these three distributions. I thought that poisson is what you get when you sum n number of exponentially distributed variables, but if seems that gamma is the same...Could someone describe the relationship in layman's terms?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Poisson and exponential distributions are very strongly related but they're fundamentally different because the Poisson is discrete (a count variable) and the exponential is continuous (a waiting *time*).

So how are they related?

If the time between a certain type of event is exponentially distributed with rate $\lambda$, then the number of events in a given time period of length $t$ follows a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$.

For example, if shooting stars appear in the sky at a rate of $\lambda$ per unit time, then the time you wait until you see your first shooting star is distributed exponentially with rate $\lambda$. If you watch the night sky for $t$ units of time, then you could see $0, 1, 2, ...$ shooting stars. The number of shooting stars that you count in this time is a $\text{Poisson}(\lambda t)$ random variable.

But what if you ask, how long must I wait before I see $n$ shooting stars?

The answer is a sum of independent exponentially distributed random variables, and it follows a $\text{gamma}(\lambda, n)$ distribution (also sometimes called an [Erlang distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution), to distinguish it from the general gamma distribution where $n$ is allowed to be a non-integer).

Comment: thank you this was very clear :)

Comment: @Stanley is it possible to express the Poisson distribution in terms of the gamma distribution.

Comment: Why formula $Pois(k, \lambda t)$ differs from $\Gamma(t, k, \lambda)$ (where gamma is parametrized by shape and rate). Am I right that $\Gamma(t, k + 1, \lambda) = \lambda Pois(k, \lambda t)$ for integer k?

Comment: @AlexanderLedovsky, did you clarify this? I'm curious too